# entity framework 6.1 duplicate unique index exception handling

Tags: entity-framework-6.1

How can I handle `duplicate key row with unique index` SqlException using `[Index(IsUnique = true)]` attribute in entity framework 6.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is a quick hack

```
try
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateException e)
{
    SqlException innerException = null;
    Exception tmp = e;
    while(innerException == null && tmp!=null)
    {
        if (tmp != null)
        {
            innerException = tmp.InnerException as SqlException;
            tmp = tmp.InnerException;
        }

    }
    if (innerException != null && innerException.Number == 2601)
    {
        // handle exception
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**I hope there is a better solution...**

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `ValidateEntity` in your dbContext and do your logic here.

**I've posted about generic way how to do it in CodeProject**

**[Validate a Unique Constraint at dbContext ValidateEntity in Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1143215/Validate-a-Unique-Constraint-at-dbContext-Validate)**